# How to find XML node existence with XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an XML file, that may or may not contain a node called "social".

I want to know if it exists or not using XSLT 1.0.

The problem is I don't know at what level in the XML structure the node will exists. It might be root level, it might be a dozen children down.

Is there an efficient way I can traverse the tree to see if it exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the test / xpath you need is `//social`, for example:

```
<xsl:if test="//social">
    <!-- Logic for if the //social node exists in the document -->
</xsl:if>
```

See [XPath Syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp)